# IBM Watson JavaScript SDK for Speech-To-Text WebSocket Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I'm writing a Vue.js web app and trying to access the Watson Speech-To-Text API. I found a very simple implementation using the JavaScript SDK (watson-speech) in documentation. This is the code I'm using:

```
    execute () {
     var stream;
     fetch('/api/speech-to-text/token').then(function(response) {
       return response.text();
     }).then(function (token) {

       stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeFile({
         token: token,
         file: document.querySelector('#audiofile').files[0],
         play: true, // play the audio out loud
         outputElement: '#output', // CSS selector or DOM Element (optional)
         }
       });

       stream.on('error', function(err) {
           console.log(err);
       });

     }).catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
 }
```

There's a button that when clicked (after a file upload) runs this execute() function.

When I run this at the link where I found it (https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/file-upload.html), it works just fine. I've configured the environment variables to use my API username and password (and confirmed they work by downloading an example React project from another Watson repository). When I try to do it in my own project however, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

I'm not sure if this is a CORS issue, or if this can't be done all client-side or what. Does WebSocket need to be installed? I had thought it was all handled by the Watson functions, so I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Found out that you CANNOT retrieve an authorization token client side. You have to have some sort of server side code to retrieve the token, and then the client can use that. Watson also has a Node.js SDK that can be used for this with easy handling of authentication.